# Design Question: Best 'place' to parse Scrapy text in Items?

Tags: python, scrapy, middleware

This question is specifically on, from a architecture/design perspective, where is the best place to parse text obtained from a response object in Scrapy?

Context:

- I'm learning Python and starting with scraping data from a popular NFL football database site
- I've gotten all the data points I need, and have them stored in a local database (sqlite)
- One thing I am scraping is a 'play by play', which collects the things that happen in every play. There is a descriptive text field that may say things like "**Player XYZ threw a pass to Player ABC**" or "**Player 123 ran the ball up the middle**".

I'd like to take that text field, parse it, and categorize it into general groups such as "**Passing Play**", "**Rushing Play**" etc based off certain keyword patterns.

My question is as follows: When and where is the best place to do that? Do I create my own middleware in Scrapy so that by the time it reaches the pipeline the item already has the categories and thus is stored in my database? Or do I just collect the scraped responses 'raw', store directly in my DB and do data cleaning in SQL after the fact, or even via a separate python script?

As mentioned, new to programming as a whole so I'm not sure what's best from a 'design' perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you doing any scraping in scrapy, you will have to think about which item fields you want to use to collect the data. So figuring out what those fields are before you write your scraper is a first.

I don't necessarily think you need your own middleware unless your data is particularly needing work done in terms of requests and responses. The middlewares are mostly useful for processing reqeuest and responses rather than data manipulation/cleaning. i.e if you have duplicates or needing to change responses or add requests etc...

Scrapy is built for data extraction and has already a robust way of putting that information into a Dictionary-like API called an ItemsAdapter, which is essentially a wrapper for different ways of storing data.

There also ways to clean data in small ways and in larger ways within Scrapy. You can ItemLoaders which puts your items through a small function that can manipulate data or use a pipeline. Pipelines give you lots of flexibility in handling extracted data.

You  will have to think about database design and what tables you're going to use, because ultimately that is where you will putting your data. It's quite easy to setup a Database Pipeline in Scrapy. The database pipeline is flexibly enough for you place data into any table you want using SQL queries.

Familiarising yourself with the Scrapy Architecture here might help you create a mental model of the process. You can see this [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

Comment: thank you very much! This was the answer I was looking for :)